# Pulling an object from user Model using $pull , having issues with multiple object items

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to delete a post object from a user model, I hold these refrences to the post they have created, this is how I am trying to currently pull the post

```
        userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            { email: req.query.email, posts: req.query.postid },
            // { $pull: { posts: req.query.postid } },
            { $pull: { posts : { number: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.postid) } }},
            { new: true },
            function (error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    res.json("error in /testing backend ===",error)
                }
                console.log(`Post id ===== ${req.query.postid}`);
                console.log(`Email===== ${req.query.email}`);
                console.log(`returning user====${user}`)
                res.json('Successfully updated user');
            }
        );
```

this is how I have created the post

```
userModel.findOne({ email: req.body.author }, function(error, user) {
            const locationURL = req.files.map((item) => item.location);

            postModel.create({ ...req.body, image: locationURL }, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
                if (error) {
                    throw new Error(error);
                }
                user.posts.push({ number: returnedDocuments._id, title: req.body.title, image: locationURL });
                user.save((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
```

I originally had only 1 item pushed into the user model, but added a few more items, then I was having issues pulling the object, thanks for your help.

this is from my DB as to my posts array

[image]

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: no error, post gets deleted but user model does not get updated

Answer (score 0):

For an array of objects, you can pull your desired document using the positional operator `{ "<array>.$" : value }`.

```
{ $pull: { posts.$.number : req.query.postid }}
```

You can check out the docs on [positional operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to learn more.

Comment: i get an error ```"errmsg": "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.",```

Comment: Does req.query.postid match the number field? @jcx3x

Comment: I had an issue because the number is an object id , this is my current solution

```

  userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
   { email: req.query.email },
   { $pull: { posts: { number: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.postid) } } },
   { new: true },


```